# Swift changing constraints depending on device orientation

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

When the device is rotated from portrait to landscape, the width constraint of the view is updated but it does not update when the device is rotated from landscape to portrait

My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    theView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    theView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    theView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    theView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    theView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
  }

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
```

When the device is first rotated from portrait to landscape 'theView' width get the 50% of the view width

```
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {  
       theView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.50).isActive = true
```

Rotating from landscape to portrait does not restore the original width

```
    } else {
       theView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.00).isActive = true
    }   
}
```

Here is an image that shows what I am trying to do.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You should disable right anchor constraint when rotating.**

Because `constraint` method of the `NSLayoutAnchor` class always returns the new, inactive constraint you should keep the reference to the constraints you want to **activate/deactivate**.

The initialization may look like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // ...        
    widthConstraint = theView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.50)
    rightConstraint = theView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0)
    rightConstraint.isActive = true
}
```

Having these references you can implement your `willRotate:` method like this.

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        rightConstraint.isActive = false
        widthConstraint.isActive = true
    }
    else {
        rightConstraint.isActive = true
        widthConstraint.isActive = false
    }
}
```

It should look like this.

[image: Ilustration of the solution]

Comment: Kamil, In landscape it works, but rotating to portrait does not restore the width to100%

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you @Kamil